# There is 0 users when installed vtiger crm 6.4 or 6.3

Tags: vtiger

when I install vtiger 6.4 on the centos6.5.
My website config are :php5.3,mysql5.5.

[image]

It always return 0 users.I can't add any acl 'Assigned To' on the system ,anyone can help me !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem,mysql database charset set is utf8 and database collation is utf8_bin,and it always return 0 users;

At last I change the database collation to utf8_general_ci ,it can work well!